# media min-width don't work correctly in order specified

Tags: css

i try to resize div.social-menu-item. but order of @media min-width don't work correctly for me. 
when my screen is less than 500px it uses @media (min-width: 768px).

minimum width is earlier, @media min-width 240px is written before 540px is written before 768px

I can have a question why?!!
I don't know how to resolve this bug!!!
see below picture for more...

```
.social-menu-item {
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    display: inline-table;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) {
    .social-menu-item {
        width: 50%;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 568px) {
    .social-menu-item {
        width: 25%;
        background: #000;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .social-menu-item {
        width: 12%;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

live in http://namvarii.ir/ social icons.

i used max-width for resolve this problem for me, but it's not correct it.

- This problem doesn't solved,
  cause i think the view slider have fixed. 
  And when i change browser size CSS min-width or max-width don't affect to element. and this problem cant solved!!

Comment: Please add your code in the question itself, as text not as image. Also the line numbers reported by this screenshot of the dev tools seems to show a correct cascading behavior.

Comment: ok, i added code for more readability

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/v3g9wu1s/ What was your expected result exactly? The "C" in "CSS" is for "Cascading", so yes rules that come later have higher priority over the ones with equivalent selectors that were set before.

Comment: @kaiido please see picture, can u describe when screen is low than 200px, media (min-width 768px) work?! have any idea?

Comment: I saw that screenshot already, and once again everything in there is normal: (768px) is set at line 1642 while (568px) is set at 1636. Since both rules inside are the same, the one defined after (768px) is overriding the previous one (568px). That's just how CSS works. Like if you do `body { background: red; background: green}` it will be green.

Comment: For the "screen is low than 200px" this screenshot doesn't show that at all, all we have there is the dev-tools.

Comment: @Kaiido but screenshot taken when screen is low than 400px, below 768px.

Comment: @Kaiido see full picture in developer mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width` instead. That should apply the rules in the order that you need:

```
max-width 768px = 568 -> 768
max-width 568px = 240 -> 568
max-width: 240px = 0 -> 240
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/antonbks/pen/oNvzyLP

Comment: used before, max-width 568 writeen before 568px before 240px. when use this method,  not any of that code affect. if i use out of @media any css for .social-menu-item, it affect

Comment: if i use @media (max-width: 560px) { .social-menu-item {width:50px}} dont affect anything in .social-menu-item when my screen is 360px.

Comment: Check the codepen, I changed the breakpoints a bit because its hard to get 240px on a codepen

Comment: i know man, i know it must work, but in my problem it is not work, i tried it. dont work!! i dont know what is problem. why not work it ?!!!

Comment: If you can put all your code in a codepen I could take a look

Comment: i tried it, in codepen it worked. but in browser directly it dont work.

Comment: Show me your codepen, ill test it directly in the browser

Comment: https://codepen.io/antonbks/pen/mdbrjVP works for me in browser as well

Comment: see picture 2, in developer mode

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HpqjgBy Using the codepen I linked before. There is an issue with the mobile emulator where your queries don't seem to be applied for me but just resizing the window in desktop mode I have the correct queries applied.

Answer (score 0):

In media query use min and max width as you are trying to make responsive and trying to support on basis of conditional width